# A 32x32 matrix with the best rank * span_weight

Tags: error-correction

**Answers must contain a 32x32 matrix (or smaller). An answer is better if its matrix has a higher product of rank and span weight.**

In ["Subsystem codes with spatially local generators"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1029). Sergey Bravyi proves that you can turn a bit matrix into a local planar subsystem code that has the following properties:

- The number of stored logical qubits is the rank of the matrix
- The distance of the code is the "span weight" of the matrix. The span weight is the minimum non-zero Hamming weight in the column span or row span of the matrix (e.g. if you can xor rows together to get a row with only a few 1s, the distance will be bad).

Unfortunately, the paper doesn't give any examples of these matrices that achieve good numbers. It just gives an asymptotic proof that families of $n \times n$ matrices exist where the rank and the span weight are both $O(n)$. I want actual examples of good matrices.

Here's a 12x12 matrix ("." means 0, "1" means 1) that has rank 6 and span weight 4:

```
    1......11111
    .1....1.1111
    ..1...11.111
    ...1..111.11
    ....1.1111.1
    .....111111.
    .111111.....
    1.1111.1....
    11.111..1...
    111.11...1..
    1111.1....1.
    11111......1
```

This matrix has a score of 6*4 = 24. This is a bad score. How high can we get the score, limited to matrices of size at most 32x32?

Here is code I wrote that you can use to analyze a matrix. I have not extensively tested it:

```
import numpy as np


def basis_rows(m: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    m = np.copy(m)
    _h, w = m.shape
    m_rank = 0
    for col in range(w):
        pivots = np.flatnonzero(m[:, col])
        if len(pivots) == 0 or pivots[-1] < m_rank:
            continue
        # Pick one row to use as the basis and simplify the others.
        pivot = pivots[-1]
        for p in pivots[:-1]:
            m[p] ^= m[pivot]
        # Swap pivot row to upper triangular area.
        if pivot != m_rank:
            m[pivot] ^= m[m_rank]
            m[m_rank] ^= m[pivot]
            m[pivot] ^= m[m_rank]
        # Grow upper triangular area
        m_rank += 1
    return m[:m_rank, :]


def rank(m: np.ndarray) -> int:
    return basis_rows(m).shape[0]


def span_weight(m: np.ndarray) -> int:
    return min(col_span_weight(m), row_span_weight(m))


def col_span_weight(m: np.ndarray) -> int:
    return row_span_weight(np.transpose(m))


def row_span_weight(m: np.ndarray) -> int:
    b = basis_rows(m)
    h, w = b.shape
    assert h <= 20, "brute force span computation will be too slow"
    power_b = np.zeros(shape=(2**h, w), dtype=np.bool_)
    for k in range(h):
        power_b.shape = (2**k, 2, 2**(h - k - 1), w)
        power_b[:, 1] ^= b[k]
    power_b.shape = (2**h, w)
    return np.min(np.count_nonzero(power_b, axis=1)[1:])


def mat(s: str) -> np.ndarray:
    d = {'_': 0, '.': 0, '0': 0, '1': 1}
    return np.array(
        [
            [
                d[c]
                for c in line
            ]
            for line in s.replace(' ', '').strip().splitlines()
        ],
        dtype=np.bool_,
    )


def analyze_matrix(m: np.ndarray):
    r = rank(m)
    s = span_weight(m)
    print(f"num_logical (rank) = {r}")
    print(f"distance (span weight) = {s}")
    print(f"score = {r*s}")
```

For example:

```
analyze_matrix(mat("""
    1......11111
    .1....1.1111
    ..1...11.111
    ...1..111.11
    ....1.1111.1
    .....111111.
    .111111.....
    1.1111.1....
    11.111..1...
    111.11...1..
    1111.1....1.
    11111......1
"""))
```

Prints:

```
num_logical (rank) = 6
distance (span weight) = 4
score = 24
```

Comment: Walsh Hadamard Matrices 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform seem like they would be good for this.

Comment: @JonasAnderson Those have a span weight of 1.

Comment: For $H_1, H_2, H_3$ (mapping $1\rightarrow 1$ and $-1\rightarrow 0$) in the link above I get (rank, span wt) = $(2,1), (3,2), (4,4)$, respectively.  I think I'm using your code correctly.

Comment: @JonasAnderson Please phrase your answer in the form of an actual specific matrix made up of 1s and 0s that I can copy paste to pass into the analyze function to verify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06319 describes a general procedure for constructing such matrices from two classical codes (Equation 60) : $$A=G_1^T Q G_2$$ where $G_i$ is the generator matrix of a classical $[n_i,k,d_i]$ code. $Q$ is an arbitrary invertible $k \times k$ matrix which can be taken to be the identity.
Then using GAP/GUAVA or sites like this for best known codes http://www.codetables.de/BKLC/Tables.php?q=2&n0=1&n1=256&k0=1&k1=256 you can construct many examples. For a $32 \times 32$ matrix choosing the best $[32,17,8]$ code for $G_1$ and $G_2$ and $Q=I$ gives $A=$

```
 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 .
 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . 1 . .
 . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 . . 1 .
 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 1 . . .
 . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . 1 1 . 1 1 .
 . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 1 . . . 1 . 1 1 1 1 1
 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 1 . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1
 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . . . . . 1 1 . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 .
 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 1 1 . 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 . 1 1 1 1 . . . . 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . 1 1 . . 1 1
 1 . . 1 1 1 . . . 1 . 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . 1
 1 1 1 . . 1 . . 1 1 . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 1 . 1 . 1 . . 1 1 . 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1 . . . 1 . 1 1 1 .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1 . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 1 . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 1 1 1 . . 1 . . 1 1 1 . . 1 . . 1 1 1 . . 1 . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 1 . 1 1 . . 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 1 1 . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 1 . 1 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . 1 . . . 1 1 1 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 . .
 1 . 1 1 1 1 1 . . 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . 1 1
 . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 1 . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 1 . 1 1
 . 1 . . 1 1 1 . . 1 1 . . . 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . . 1 1 1 . . 1 1 1
 1 . 1 . 1 1 . . 1 1 . 1 . 1 . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 .
 . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1 1 . 1 . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 . 1
```

with a **score=136** (rank=17,weight=8). This should be the largest possible with this construction. (For $12 \times 12$ the best score is 28; For $16 \times 16$ the best score is 44; For $24 \times 24$ the best score is 96;)

Answer (score 4):

$H_4=$

```
1111111111111111
1010101010101010
1100110011001100
1001100110011001
1111000011110000
1010010110100101
1100001111000011
1001011010010110
1111111100000000
1010101001010101
1100110000110011
1001100101100110
1111000000001111
1010010101011010
1100001100111100
1001011001101001
```

returns

num_logical (rank) = 5
distance (span weight) = 8
score = 40

Note, $H_k$ ($2^k \times 2^k$) matrices can be constructed using the formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform and setting $-1\rightarrow 0$.

It can also be created using the kronecker product:

```
H1 = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
H2 = np.kron(H1, H1)
H4 = np.kron(H2, H2)
H5 = np.kron(H4, H1)
H = H5 == 1
analyze_matrix(H)
print('\n'.join(''.join('_1'[int(e)] for e in row) for row in H))
```

prints:

```
num_logical (rank) = 6
distance (span weight) = 16
score = 96
11111111111111111111111111111111
1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_
11__11__11__11__11__11__11__11__
1__11__11__11__11__11__11__11__1
1111____1111____1111____1111____
1_1__1_11_1__1_11_1__1_11_1__1_1
11____1111____1111____1111____11
1__1_11_1__1_11_1__1_11_1__1_11_
11111111________11111111________
1_1_1_1__1_1_1_11_1_1_1__1_1_1_1
11__11____11__1111__11____11__11
1__11__1_11__11_1__11__1_11__11_
1111________11111111________1111
1_1__1_1_1_11_1_1_1__1_1_1_11_1_
11____11__1111__11____11__1111__
1__1_11__11_1__11__1_11__11_1__1
1111111111111111________________
1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1__1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1
11__11__11__11____11__11__11__11
1__11__11__11__1_11__11__11__11_
1111____1111________1111____1111
1_1__1_11_1__1_1_1_11_1__1_11_1_
11____1111____11__1111____1111__
1__1_11_1__1_11__11_1__1_11_1__1
11111111________________11111111
1_1_1_1__1_1_1_1_1_1_1_11_1_1_1_
11__11____11__11__11__1111__11__
1__11__1_11__11__11__11_1__11__1
1111________1111____11111111____
1_1__1_1_1_11_1__1_11_1_1_1__1_1
11____11__1111____1111__11____11
1__1_11__11_1__1_11_1__11__1_11_
```

Comment: This one was surprising to me because I normally think of the Hadamard matrix as being a basis, meaning I can form a vector like [1,0,0,0,...,0] meaning I can form single-entry vectors suggesting a span weight of 1. Except that only works over R, not over Z2, because it relies on being able to multiple a vector by 2 or by -1!

Comment: Pure numerology conjecture: $H_k$ has rank $k+1$ and span wt $2^{k-1}$.

Comment: I also wasn't very clear in my comment.

Comment: I added H5 to your answer since it's an at-most-32x32 matrix with a better score (96).

Answer (score 3):

For n = 16 this matrix has a score of 10*4=40:

```
analyze_matrix(mat("""1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
                    0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
                    0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
                    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
                    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
                    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
                    1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
                    0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1"""))
```

prints

```
num_logical (rank) = 10
distance (span weight) = 4
score = 40
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a $24 \times 24$ matrix with the same score as $H_5$ (rank=12, weight = 8, score = 96)

```
 1 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . .
 1 1 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
 . 1 1 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . . . .
 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . .
 . 1 . 1 1 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . .
 1 . 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . .
 . 1 1 . . 1 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
 1 . . 1 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . .
 . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . . .
 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
 . 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
 1 . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1
 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1
 . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 .
 . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . 1
 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . 1 1 .
 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1 . 1 1 . 1 .
 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1 . 1
 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . 1 1 1 . 1 1 .
 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . 1 1 . 1 1 1 . . 1
 . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 . 1
 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1 1 .
 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . 1 1
```

(it's based on extended binary golay code)